# Webpack 4 - typescript entry file

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

I am setting up my small personal project and stumbled upon an issue with typescript and react. When I use index.js as my entry point everything goes fine, but when I use the .tsx file I get following error:

```
EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'
```

I could just ive up and use .js, but I;m curious whyit is happening. Detailed error message specifies that it just looks for .wasm, .mjs, .js and .json file extensions, ignoring whatever I put into resolve: { extensions: [] }.

```
no extension
  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  [path_to_project]\src\index doesn't exist
.wasm
  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  [path_to_project]\src\index.wasm doesn't exist
.mjs
  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  [path_to_project]\src\index.mjs doesn't exist
.js
  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  [path_to_project]\src\index.js doesn't exist
.json
  Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  [path_to_project]\src\index.json doesn't exist
```

My webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.export = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.tsx'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'pfgen.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.d.ts', '.tsx']
    }
};
```

Here is my project repository: [REPOSITORY](https://github.com/wolframowy/pf2lootgen) 
And here is webpack versions that I am using:

```
"ts-loader": "^5.3.1",
"typescript": "^3.2.2",
"webpack": "^4.27.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
```

Comment: please accept @patrick-ramser answer if your problem was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change module.export to module.**exports**. Just pulled, changed, and built successfully on my end using your Git repo.

As an aside, also add /node_modules to your .gitignore so an editor like VSCode doesn't look at that directory when comparing to master.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! That would be the last place I would be looking for an error. It works now.